# Wordpress and platform in subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, nginx, pydio

Sorry if this a duplicate question, but I'm not sure how to solve this issue.

Currently I have a wordpress site in /var/www/html directory.
This wordpress site is integrated with the Pydio System (Secure File Sharing for business), just like a subdomain. Both systems are linked with a plugin called ajaxplorer.
The Pydio system is in /var/www/html/pydio directory. So, this one is like a subdirectory for wordpress site.

All works fine when I navigate into http://mysite.example/pydio... But using the pydio system, if I navigate to some url like: http://mysite.example/pydio/ws-inbox/ and then, I then refresh the page, it redirects to the wordpress site again, but the URL stills the same: http://mysite.example/pydio/ws-inbox/, showing a wordpress 404 page error. (as when you are looking for a post)... so I need navigate again to http://mysite.example/pydio/ in order to access the pydio system again.

What I want is that when I refresh the url: http://mysite.example/pydio/ws-inbox/, it remains in the same Pydio system, and do not redirect to wordpress.

I have been searching about and trying to create a .htaccess, (because my WP directory do not have an .htaccess before) but without success.

Instead, Pydio folder has the following .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# You must set the correct values here if you want
# to enable webDAV sharing. The values assume that your
# Pydio installation is at http://yourdomain/
# and that you want the webDAV shares to be accessible via
# http://yourdomain/shares/repository_id/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /dms
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^shares ./dav.php [L]
RewriteRule ^api ./rest.php [L]
RewriteRule ^ocs/ ./opencollab.php [L]
RewriteRule ^ocs-provider/ ./opencollab.php [L]
RewriteRule ^user ./index.php?get_action=user_access_point [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pydio/index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pydio/plugins
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pydio/dashboard|^/pydio/settings|^/pydio/welcome|^/pydio/ws-
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]

#Following lines seem to be necessary if PHP is working
#with apache as CGI or FCGI. Just remove the #
#See http://doc.tiki.org/WebDAV#Note_about_Apache_with_PHP_as_fcgi_or_cgi

#RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
#RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

#Following lines may be necessary for a PHP-FPM setup
# to make sure that authorization is transmitted.
# Just remove the # at the beginning of the line

#SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

</IfModule>

AddType application/json .json
```

So, maybe someone knows how could I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please go to `settings` > `permalink` then update and check url.

Comment: Hi @Arshid KV, thanks for your response. Currently I have the following settings in my permalinks page:

Common Settings: Day and name;
Product Permalinks: Default;
Optional: All fields empty;

Sorry, could you provide me a little bit more info about what should I do?